# Build HTML struts 2 tags from java string

Tags: java, html, jsp, struts2, struts-tags

I want to build HTML struts2 tags from java string.
For example in my java string code:

```
String htmlCode = "<s:a href=\"index.action\"> Index </s:a> ";
```

And in the JSP, i put a code:

```xml
<s:property value="htmlCode" escapeHtml="false"/>
```

So the output will make a link `<a href="http://index.action">Index</a>`

But, after i compiled the result just a text without link "**Index**"

How can I solve this problem ?

Comment: Have you tried using <s:url/> with <s:property/> tag ?? Something like this <s:url value='<s:property vaue="ActionName"/>'  var="indx" /><s:a  href="%{indx}"    >Index</s:a>

Answer (score 0):

You can (but should not, use it only as an exception and only when strictly necessary) build HTML serverside and print it in page by specifying `escapeHtml="false"` on `<s:property />` like you are doing.

You can't obviously mount STRUTS TAGS server-side, because `<s:property />` will render text, and if appropriately instructed, HTML, XML, Javascript, etc... but **it will absolutely not compile Struts tags itself**.

Then you could do

```
String htmlCode = "<a href=\"index.action\"> Index <a>";
```

but the best thing is to do it on the page.

If you have this url in many places and want to avoid repeating the tag, just use `<s:set />` and refer to the calculated value once. Also try using `<s:url />` when building action URLs.

Comment: You're welcome @wisnusm. Please mark the answer as accepted (by clicking the white V in top left corner of the answer) if it helped, thank you